# Mac:homebrew not installing all the Kafka scripts

Tags: homebrew, apache-kafka

I have installed kafka-0.8.2.2 using homebrew as mentioned in the below link
https://dtflaneur.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/installing-kafka-on-mac-osx/

i have configured only 1 broker..

Able to run zookeeper,kafka ,consumer,producer and publish messages using producer console and see messages in consumer console...

but when im trying to run below script im seeing this script is missing..

- kafka-consumer-groups.sh

basically i want to see the

- **consumer group list**
- **number of partitions available** (would like to know the number of partitions present in broker)

and when i ran echo $KAFKA_HOME  it gives empty i mean no value...

but when i ran brew install kafka
Warning: kafka-0.8.2.2 already installed

im concerened if kafka is installed properly..please suggest

able to see below scripts under usr/local/bin/

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh
kafka-console-producer.sh
kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh
kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh
kafka-mirror-maker.sh
kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh
kafka-producer-perf-test.sh
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh
kafka-replay-log-producer.sh
kafka-replica-verification.sh
kafka-run-class.sh
kafka-server-start.sh
kafka-server-stop.sh
kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh
kafka-topics.sh
```

not sure if any other scripts were than which i pointed out...

Answer (score 1):

`kafka-consumer-groups.sh` is only available from `0.9`.

Each topic (not broker) consists of partitions, so to check out partitions of a topic you can use:
`/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic your_topic_name`

I don't know about brew installation of Kafka, since I'm using Docker, where you have a single command installation and you don't mess with your local file system. I wholeheartedly suggest that you try that (I can provide you with more details about that if you choose to go the Docker way).

Comment: Thanks When i ran the above command it gave number of partitions as "1"...can i assume this as default number of partitions??as i havent configured any partitions during kafka installation..if have to increase the number of partitions for the topic...should i use "kafka-reassign-partitions.sh" please lemme know the sample commad to achieve the same??

Comment: `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic your_topic_name --partitions 10`

Comment: BTW `consumer group name` is something that you set when you consume from Kafka using high-level (also called group-based) consumer (or a tool you use uses high-level consumer, e.g. fluentd or logstash). If N consumers are part of a group they all get 1/N subset of messages from a topic (used to increase parallelism, even using consumers on different hosts).

Answer (score 0):

After brew installing, you'll have some print out akin to this:

```
To restart kafka after an upgrade:
  brew services restart kafka
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start /opt/homebrew/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

You can then run `/opt/homebrew/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups`